# How can I enable the html attributes autocomplete in eclipse luna 4.4?

Tags: html, eclipse, netbeans, autocomplete

How can I enable the html **attributes** autocomplete in eclipse luna 4.4?

Such as in Netbeans, I can get the html **attributes** autocomplete like this,

[image]

But the autocomplete for **attributes** seems does not come with eclipse. Do I need to install some kind of plugin for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes install [Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP)](http://eclipse.org/webtools/)
or use Use [Aptana studio](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download.html)